# Filters and chaining of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have two filters that get checked for my Rails model called Items. If both filters are enabled, Ie: certain params are passed then it filters down the Items based on the first one and then should use the results of the first filter as the basis to filter from the second. But it doesn't like me calling .where on the instance variable of @items which is being passed to my view? Any thoughts?

Error is :
    undefined method `where' for #

Code:

```
@coasters = Coaster.all

    if params[:type]
      type = params[:type]
      if type == 'powered'
        @coasters = @coasters.where("style = ?", "powered")
      else
        @coasters = @coasters.where("material LIKE ?", params[:type])
      end
    end

    if params[:letters]
      letters = params[:letters]
      if letters == '#'
        @coasters = @coasters.all.select { |r| /^[0-9].*/ =~ r.name }
      else
        letters = letters.split('-')
        lettersLower = (letters[0]..letters[1]).to_a
        lettersUpper = (letters[0].upcase..letters[1].upcase).to_a
        letters = lettersLower.concat(lettersUpper)
        conditions = (letters.map{ |letter| " name ILIKE '#{letter}%' " }.join('OR'))
        @coasters = @coasters.where(conditions)
      end
    end
```

Comment: Post the full error message. Are you sure no other action is taken on the @coasters object between the `.all` and the `.where`? Because it looks like you're changing the type of the @coasters object from relation to something else.

Comment: I fixed this, the query was executing when I used .all on Coaster, so changed .all to .scoped and that solved it.